# text-align: right; not working for <label>

Tags: html, css, forms, label, alignment

Simply enough I can't get text to align to right in a `<label>` element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contact_form">
 <label for="name" id="name_label">Name:</label>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contact_form label {
  text-align: right;
}
```

My page: http://freshbeer.lv/development/en/contact.php

You can see labels for name, phone, email etc... are aligned to the left, but I need them to be aligned to the right, so could anyone please suggest something?

Comment: give display block property to label and it will work

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`Label` is an inline element - so, unless a width is defined, its width is exact the same which the letters span. Your `div` element is a block element so its width is by default 100%.

You will have to place the `text-align: right;` on the `div` element in your case, or applying `display: block;` to your `label`

Another option is to set a width for each label and then use `text-align`. The `display: block` method will not be necessary using this.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a text align to the right inside of any element, including labels.

Html:

```
<label>Text</label>
```

Css:

```
label {display:block; width:x; height:y; text-align:right;}
```

This way, you give a width and height to your label and make any text inside of it align to the right.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in other answers, label is an inline element. However, you can apply `display: inline-block` to the label and then center with `text-align`.

```
#name_label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Why `display: inline-block` and not `display: inline`? For the same reason that you can't align `label`, it's inline.

Why `display: inline-block` and not `display: block`? You could use `display: block`, but it will be on another line. `display: inline-block` combines the properties of `inline` and `block`. It's inline, but you can also give it a width, height, and align it.